# How to get specific content from wikipedia?

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to make something like a personal TV guide which will display the title and the airdate of the last available episode of H.I.M.Y.M and TBBT.

As a resource for this information I decided to use Wikipedia. I know Wikipedia has it's own API and I've been looking through the documentation for quite a while but it's really extensive and I don't know where to start. So far I've got to the point where I'm querying this URL:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&title=List_of_How_I_Met_Your_Mother_episodes&prop=info&format=dbg
```

and receiving the following array:

```
array (
  'query' => 
  array (
    'pages' => 
    array (
      6048517 => 
      array (
        'pageid' => 6048517,
        'ns' => 0,
        'title' => 'List of How I Met Your Mother episodes',
        'touched' => '2011-01-25T15:33:45Z',
        'lastrevid' => 409077359,
        'counter' => 0,
        'length' => 4417,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

The problem is I have no idea how to get to the actual data I'm looking for :/
Maybe somebody out there has a bit more exprerience with the Wikipedia API and can somehow help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: If you are familar with RDF, you may be interested in DBPedia http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Big_Bang_Theory

Answer (score 3):

Note that the MediaWiki API only allows access to the MediaWiki kind of information. A wiki is some kind of collection of *text* pages. There is no inherit semantic within the way the MediaWiki software stores the information on Wikipedia. Everything is done via special, text-based formatting.

So even if you find general and consistent information about something on Wikipedia, it is not because the software did it, but because the authors decided on a common standard to display the data. As such, to get the actual semantic out of the wiki, you need to parse the information yourself. You can use the MediaWiki API to get the exact *text representation* the software stores for an article, and parse the information you are looking for out of the text. Of course this requires that you know *where* and *how* particular information is *usually* displayed. And of course, there is no guarantee, that it will work all the time, or for every page you test.